# Jenkins Multibranch pipeline cannot find Jenkinsfile in subfolder

Tags: jenkins

I am using a Jenkins Multibranch pipeline -- specifically, an Organization folder, which monitors all my Bitbucket repos and builds a pipeline for any repo containing a Jenkinsfile. For simplicity, I have configured it to look at only 1 of my repos for now.

Here's my problem:

When the Jenkinsfile is located in the root folder of my repo, everything works fine -- Jenkins sees the Jenkinsfile, and creates the pipeline as defined in that Jenkinsfile.

```
repo
|
|___> Jenkinsfile
```

[image: Screenshot: Jenkins configured to look for Jenkinsfile in root folder]

As you can see, Jenkins finds it without any issues:
[image: Screenshot: Jenkins finds Jenkinsfile in root folder]

---

However, I want to move the Jenkinsfile to a subfolder in my repo (giving me the flexibility to have multiple pipelines defined for 1 repo).
When I move it to a subfolder (`jenkins/ci-pipeline/Jenkinsfile`), even though I explicitly give that relative file path to Jenkins, it can no longer find the Jenkinsfile!!

```
repo
|
|___> jenkins
       |
       |___> ci-pipeline
              |
              |___> Jenkinsfile
```

[image: Screenshot: Jenkins configured to look for Jenkinsfile in subfolder]

As you can see, despite giving the relative file path (`jenkins/ci-pipeline/Jenkinsfile`) to Jenkins, it claims it can no longer find the Jenkinsfile:
[image: Screenshot: Jenkins cannot find Jenkinsfile in subfolder]

Incidentally, even though the description of that Jenkins field says it is the "relative location", I tried to give it an absolute file path (`${WORKSPACE}/jenkins/ci-pipeline/Jenkinsfile`) instead to see if that would work:
[image: Screenshot: Jenkins configured with absolute path of subfolder]

Unfortunately, that didn't work either -- also, Jenkins didn't expand its `WORKSPACE` environment variable:
[image: Screenshot: Jenkins cannot find Jenkinsfile in subfolder, even with absolute path]

I have also logged into my Jenkins worker node and confirmed that the Jenkinsfile is present in that subfolder, within the Jenkins workspace for my repo.

---

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?? 
This seems very simple, but it just refuses to work and it's driving me nuts!

Comment: `${WORKSPACE}` won't work because there isn't a workspace until a build is actually running.  In other words, there is no workspace when just scanning for repos/branches in a Multibranch Pipeline folder.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be caused by the fact that I have an outdated version of the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin (2.2.9).

For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791004/5505583